# How to create click event listener on span text in formattedString?

Tags: nativescript

I am using formattedString to display a text with clickable link. And i need help in adding the tap event on the text(formattedString.spans.text)

```
let span = new Span();
span.textdecoration = 'underline'
span.on('tap', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can not. It's an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3671), you may log your vote and follow up at Github.

Comment: If it's a regular web link, perhaps you could use a WebView or HtmlView instead.